# Loop in records in datatable at forumla field in crystal report

Tags: datatable, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have `datatable` attached to my `Crystal Report` with the following structure

```
TypeId
TypeName
```

I want to display `TypeName` in `GroupHeaderSection` based on condition

**For example**

if TypeId = 1 then display hans

if TypeId = 2 then display MNHS

I tried the following formula to display records from this `datatable`

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Local NumberVar result := -1;
Local NumberVar i := 1;
Local StringVar inString := "";
While i <= 5 And result = -1 Do
(
  // inString := IIF({DTPMS_RptLocationTr.LocationTypeId} = 1,{DTPMS_RptLocationTr.LocationTypeName},"")

   If {DTPMS_RptLocationTr.LocationTypeId} = 5 Then
     inString := {DTPMS_RptLocationTr.LocationTypeName};
   i := i + 1;
);
inString
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this

Comment: you want to get `hans` and `mnhs` from database when type id is 1 and 2 also are these type ids stored in database?

Comment: Yes this values stored in database and i want to display according to condition if 1 show something and if 2 show another thing etc

Comment: I would like to suggest you to create group of TypeID and place this code into group header. multiple group header can be displayed in single page. if you want to show each group in separate page then you can select option New Page After in Group Footer Section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to solve my issue.

First i changed the way records returned from database I returned the data like that

```
Type1 | Type2 | Type3
======================
hans  | MNHS  | nhues
```

so now i can bind data directly from `datatable` to report header